# PKCS#11. Possibility of performing Ecryption/Decryption in hardware

Tags: cryptographic-hardware, pkcs11

Cheers. I'm dealing with **HSM** via **PKCS#11** C/Python interface. I'm wondering is it possible to do some `C_Encrypt`/`C_Decrypt` in hardware. By saying *"in hardware"* I mean encryption/decryption without exposing the result to the caller space. This is mostly aboud decryption as I want to call `C_Decrypt` and leave the result inside the HSM as arbitrary data to do some other transformations on that data later, saying re-encrypting it on some other key. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I believe this suits more into StackExchange.

Comment: If you'd use CTR mode encryption then you could encrypt the data with a temporary key, then decrypt the data with the decryption key. You could do the same thing once you know the new key. I don't see how you could use `C_Decrypt` to a data object on the HSM, as the function expects a pointer to a byte array.

Comment: [This question has been reposted on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297923/pkcs11-possibility-of-performing-ecryption-decryption-in-hardware) While I don't necessarily see this as off-topic here (see e.g. [this recent meta thread](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/should-we-allow-crypto-specific-tool-related-questions)), we should still preferably keep all the answers in one place.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, sorry, I just thougth this question suits better for this resource. I'm closing it.

Comment: @HenadziMatuts I’ve closed it for your convenience.